# Typescript: Obtain the type parameters of a function with all declarations

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I'm trying to get an array of type parameters of a function with all the declarations (Overloads) with or concatenation.

For example, I can use the `Parameters<T>` but this function only get the last declaration.

```js
interface FOO {
    foo(a: string, b: string): string;
    foo(a: boolean, b: string): string;
    foo(a: boolean, b:string, c: number): string;
};

type params = Parameters<FOO["foo"]>; // [boolean, string, number]
```

Actually, the params type is `[boolean, string, number]` but I expect the type as `[string, string] | [boolean, string] | [boolean, string, number]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TS doesn't support infer union param type from overloaded function. The way TS function overload works is like switch-case, it eventually collapses to one of the signatures. Check this [section](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-inference-in-conditional-types):

> When inferring from a type with multiple call signatures (such as the type of an overloaded function), inferences are made from the last signature (which, presumably, is the most permissive catch-all case). It is not possible to perform overload resolution based on a list of argument types.

If such params type is important to you, you could add:

```
interface FOO {
    foo(a: string, b: string): string;
    foo(a: boolean, b: string): string;
    foo(a: boolean, b: string, c: number): string;
    foo(...args: [string, string] | [boolean, string] | [boolean, string, number]): string;
};
```

---

**Edit:** OK, I was wrong. turns out Titian the TS wizard always finds a way, even when it's officially claimed "not possible". Be sure to checkout his [brilliant answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51654917/3617380).

Comment: It can be done with some caveats.. I have an answer already but can't seem to find it :-(

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir Do show us some wizardry!!

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir  guess you mean [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51650979/type-infererence-with-overloaded-functions/51654917#51654917)

Comment: Thank you for digging up that answer, and thank you for the upvote, that upvote just earned be my legendary badge ! :D

Comment: ^ wooo, congrats! I just got to 3000 rep today